# DuplicateKeyException in JooQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq, amazon-aurora

I am using JooQ to perform CRUD operation on Aurora MySQL.

I have the following scenario:

1. If insertion fails due to duplicate key exception then retry same operation again otherwise ignore the exception.
2. If insertion fails then update the records if the conditions are met.

Is there any way to catch DuplicateKeyException only? 
JooQ is throwing exception as DataAccessException.

On enabling OnDuplicateKeyUpdate, it seems that if the record exist it will blindly update the record in database. My use case is if the record exist in database then update the record if the update conditions are met.

I can do that in two separate call of Insert and Update but is there any way t do it in single call?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

There are two questions in your question:

> Is there any way to catch DuplicateKeyException only? JooQ is throwing exception as DataAccessException.

Yes of course. jOOQ doesn't have separate exception types for individual errors like JDBC, but it still:

- References the JDBC `SQLException` that caused the [`DataAccessException`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/DataAccessException.html). You can access it through `dae.getCause()` or [`dae.getCause(SQLException.class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/DataAccessException.html#getCause-java.lang.Class-), the latter being useful in case the original `SQLException` having been wrapped several times.
- References the [`DataAccessException.sqlStateClass()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/DataAccessException.html#sqlStateClass--). The one you're looking for is [`SQLStateClass.C23_INTEGRITY_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/exception/SQLStateClass.html#C23_INTEGRITY_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION). If your JDBC driver propagates the SQL state class in its exceptions, then this information will be available to you through jOOQ.

> On enabling OnDuplicateKeyUpdate, it seems that if the record exist it will blindly update the record in database. My use case is if the record exist in database then update the record if the update conditions are met.

You could encode your update condition in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`'s `SET` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO t (id, value)
VALUES (1, 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET
  value = CASE WHEN value = 2 THEN 3 ELSE value END
```

In the above example, the `UPDATE` clause will update `value` to `3` only if it is `2`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out this SQL State class is also used for not-null constraints on insert. Would've bit me if an integration test didn't catch it.